# Changing the opacity colors by selecting the text in codeigniter php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

```
<?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
        <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>
        <div class="servicesecommerce accordion"><?php echo $r->service_name;?></div>
        <div class=" servicesetext panel">                      
            <div class="services3"><?php echo $r->text;?></div>                     
        </div>                  
<?php endforeach;endif;?>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
   this.classList.toggle("active");
   this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}
}
</script>
<script>
    $('.servicesecommerce').each( function( index ) 
    {    
        $(this).addClass('itemsss-' + index);   
    });
</script>
```

The output will be in this format
E-commerce 
Software
Digital
Mobile App Development

By default E-commerce should be highlighted  and the rest of the three should be in disable(Opacity should be low.When the user clicks on Second one remaining three div Opacity should be changed and the one which has been selected that should be highlighted with dark color.

Comment: give the three you want with low opacity a certain class and set its opacity with CSS

Comment: @Roysh when i click on second one the remaining opacity should be low

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of what you have and explain better what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Roysh by default E-commerce should be highlighted and the rest of the one should be in disabled mode.When the user click on second one(Software) the remaining three should be disabled

Comment: then you should do that with JavaScript. Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: @Roysh yes i can use jquery

Comment: So from what I understand, you have three divs withe the classes  - servicesecommerce, servicesetext and services3 - whenever one is licked it becomes active and the rest should be disabled with a certain opacity?

Comment: @Roysh I am fetching the data from backend  there are 4 as of now by default when i open the page the first one should be highlighted and the other should be disabled. When i click on the second one first,third and fourth one should be in disable mode

Comment: are you rendering 4 different divs? what's the parent div of these divs? please post what is being rendered to the browser or just create a fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155232/discussion-between-user6728960-and-roysh).

Comment: @Roysh solved my issue posting the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
                <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>
                    <div class="servicesecommerce accordion"><?php echo $r->service_name;?></div>
                    <div class=" servicesetext panel">                      
                        <div class="services3"><?php echo $r->text;?></div>                     
                    </div>                  
                <?php endforeach;endif;?>
```

Javascript : Added this code to change the opacity

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.servicesecommerce').not('.servicesecommerce:first').addClass('opacty');
$('.servicesecommerce').click(function(e){
$('.servicesecommerce').not(this).addClass('opacty');
$(this).removeClass('opacty'); 
});
</script>
```

Css Added this to change the opacity color:

```
.opacty {
opacity: .3;
}
```